# Highlight textview so as to know that it is clickable

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I have a Clickable textview in between of multiple informative textviews(which are non - interactable).

Is there any android property or UI guideline to display clickable textview. So that user will get it immediately after seeing the textview that its clickable.
Any other suggestions are welcome.

I tried giving blue color to the textView as in webpage hyperlinks, it looks bad as my background is also bluish.

Comment: you can underline text by Html.fromHtml("<u> + text + "</u>" or use spannable object to color its text for example to blue, or just color underline (i think it is possible)

Comment: @Shash do u find the solution from my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Can use SpannAbleString for This if you want to do it programatically and If you want to do it Using UI then Create a Selector for Text 
for SpanAble String Sample Snippet is Following

```
SpannableString spanScan3;
    spanScan3=new SpannableString("or register manually");

        ClickableSpan myActivityLauncher = new ClickableSpan() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent=new Intent (getApplicationContext(),ManualRegistration.class);
               startActivity(intent);
             }
           };

spanScan3.setSpan(myActivityLauncher, 12, 20, 0);
spanScan3.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green)), 12, 20, 0);
        spanScan3.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 12, 20, 0);
Scan_text_3.setText(spanScan3,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and if you want o give color Using UI here is Sample 
 make color folder in res Directory 
and in Color foldr make an xml name Like textColor.xml 
and in Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:color="@color/whiteColor"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/bluetxt"></item> 
</selector>
```

do soe thing like this and give its refrence to your textView

Answer (score 2):

Use color watever u want in the below line:

```
   <YourTextView>.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u><FONT COLOR=\"#736AAA\" >"+String+"</Font></u>"));
```

Comment: @Shash do u find the solution?